# Synergy: Can I flash the screen when mouse enters?

Tags: mouse, synergy

I am new to Synergy, which seems like a very cool product!  The problem I have is that with 6 monitors I can never find the mouse cursor.  Is there a way to flash a monitor when the cursors enters, or some other method to help locate the *active* monitor as the mouse moves?

Thanks